# Downloading Rate while downloading a file?

Tags: python, download, rate

---

```
import time # to use it later with downloading Rate,

import urllib.request # to download a file
url = "http://xxxx.xxx.com/xxx/Setup.exe"

file_name = url[-9:] # file name will be setup.exe just for Ex .


class Download(): # i'm useing a Class but its ok if you have an answer in another way .

def __init__(self):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name, self.progress)

def progress(self,block,blocksize,total):
    print("Total : \t\t",total)
    downloaded = block * blocksize
    print("Downlaoded : \t\t",downloaded)
    left = total - downloaded
    print("Left : \t\t",left)
    percent =  downloaded * 100 / total
    print("Percent : \t\t",percent)
    print("Rate : \t\t",self.rate_return(downloaded)) # i dont get it . 



def rate_return(self,current_size):
    while True:
        # here is my problem ! i know its size / time to get Rate of downloading file .
        # but its totaly wrong :(
        return (current_size/1024)/time.time()
        # size / 1024 to convert it to KB . / time in seconds .

Download()
```

.................

the output :

Total :          10913768 # Good

Downlaoded :         385024 # Good

Left :       10528744 # Good

Percent :        3.527874149423004 # Good

Rate :       2.3952649685390823e-07 # Wrong ? i know its about 1.5

the question is how to get downloading rate while the file is still downloading .

Comment: I used built in curl call and it was detailed enough. See if this works for you. curl -o {} {}'.format(path, url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the current timestamp to calculate the kbps.
Instead it should work like this:

```py
import time # to use it later with downloading Rate
import urllib.request # to download a file

# Downloading Sublime as an Example .
url = "https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%203207%20x64%20Setup.exe"
file_name = url[-9:] # file name will be setup.exe just for Ex .
class Download(): # i'm useing a Class but its ok if you have an answer in another way .
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name, self.progress)

    def progress(self,block,blocksize,total):
        print("Total : \t\t",total)
        downloaded = block * blocksize
        print("Downlaoded : \t\t",downloaded)
        left = total - downloaded
        print("Left : \t\t",left)
        percent =  downloaded * 100 / total
        print("Percent : \t\t",percent)
        print("Rate : \t\t",self.rate_return(downloaded)) # i dont get it . 

    def rate_return(self,current_size):
        #while True:  # worthless
        # here is my problem ! i know its size / time to get Rate of downloading file .
        # but its totaly wrong :(
        return (current_size / 1024) / (time.time() - self.start)
        # size / 1024 to convert it to KB . / time in seconds .

Download()
```

I couldn't test it deeply but the values seemed ok.
It is a 10MB file and before the limit of my Internet speed was reached it is finished. I wanted to test with another file but somehow it didn't work although i changed url and filename.

Comment: thanks , your method is right but why it giving me exactly the half of the real speed ! so i had to do it like :
return (current_size*2)  / (time.time() - self.start)
but im sure it not the pythonic way to do it , but it did the job . 
any aideas ?